# Scripting an escrow transaction where the arbitrator ALWAYS gets paid

Tags: script, multi-signature, smartcontracts, opcodes, escrow

I am trying to make an Escrow and Arbitration where the arbitrator always gets paid say 5% of the transaction.

As in the famous escrow [example here:](https://developer.bitcoin.org/devguide/contracts.html#escrow-and-arbitration)

Charlie-the-customer wants to buy a product from Bob-the-businessman and Alice-the-arbitrator is responsible for making sure everyone obeys the rules of the contract.

The script for this 2-of-3 multisig is:

```
OP_2 [A's pubkey] [B's pubkey] [C's pubkey] OP_3 OP_CHECKMULTISIG
```

There is an issue with this script for my use case, **Arbitrator** is only needed and will get paid if there is a problem between **Customer** and **Businessman**. **B** and **C** can just sign the transaction and not give **A** anything.

I want **A** to be always paid when the funds move from the script to any address (not before it's added in the script), can this be implemented in the script?